# Struggling with Json: Deployment - Managing Packages with NPM (free code camp)

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I'm trying to learn the basics of node.js, starting with material from Free Code Camp.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/back-end-development-and-apis/managing-packages-with-npm/how-to-use-package-json-the-core-of-any-node-js-project-or-npm-package

I've completed the 'Managing Packages with NPM' course successfully in Replit but I am now trying to do this in VS Code (to get comfortable in the real environment). I have cloned the repo from the FCC github and have pushed it to my own github profile.

Now, I'm seriously stuck with submitting the solution,the free code camp tests are not passing (stuck athe the first one!) See photo below:

[image: Screenshot of Free Code Camp failed test]

Anyone got any idea why this is happening?? The json file DOES have an author key!

I'm not doing anything different in the package.json file which all passed the tests before so I'm pretty sure it's a deployment issue.

My repo: https://github.com/mariaalouisaa/managing-packages-with-npm-FCC

Any thoughts/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the issue fixed ? because I can see that github tests are passing !!

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am trying to get the FreeCodeCamp tests to pass but they are still failing. I will link a screenshot now to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this format with author

```
{
  "author": "Barney Rubble <b@rubble.com> (http://barnyrubble.tumblr.com/)"
}
```